# Tensorflow Loss & Acc remain constant in CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss, conv-neural-network

I have just started to learn CNN on Tensorflow. However, when I train the model the Loss and accuracy don't change.

[image]

I am using images of size 128x128x3 and the images are normalized (in [0,1]). And here is the compiler that I am using.

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.000001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

And here is the summary of my model

[image]

I tried the following things but I always have the same values:

- Change the learning rate from  0.00000001 to 10
- Change the convolution kernel I tried 5x5 and 3x3
- I added another fully connected layer and a Conv layer.

**update**

The layers' weights didn't change after fitting the model. I have the same initial weights.

Comment: Is your model updating the weights after every epoch? I would recommend checking the layer weights after every epoch.

Comment: I don't know how to check the weights in every epoch. But yes, before training and after the 5 epochs I have the same weight. What is the problem ??

Comment: What is the activation you are using at the output node? And could upload your code so that I can see what is wrong. Because this seems weird why the model won't train.

Comment: I am using 'softmax'
Here is a link to my project: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rB4iplDg8Er9vPNEQAwq5s-l8T9NlRGr

Answer (score 1):

You could try this,

```
 model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Also, remove the softmax activation from the last layer, a binary classification problem does not need a softmax. So, what softmax does in this case is clip the value always to 1 since there is only one probability and thus the network doesn't train. This [link](https://medium.com/data-science-bootcamp/understand-the-softmax-function-in-minutes-f3a59641e86d) might help you understand softmax.
Additionally, you can try using sigmoid activation at the final node. That clips the output to a value in the range of 0 to 1 and the network weights wont blow up because of a very high loss.

Comment: @WassimBouatay try removing the activation in the last layer. You don't need a softmax function for a binary classification problem. That should solve the problem.

Comment: The accuracy become 0.7091 (which is 1-0.2909) in the first epochs, but it is still stuck in the same value even after 10 epochs.

Comment: Sigmoid activation at the output node should help

Comment: I think the problem is with `train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    horizontal_flip=True )`    the image generator for the current tf version. This [link] (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8595) has details regarding similar issue others are facing.